# Dealing with Overplotting and missing data of a 3-D Scatterplot in Matlab

Tags: matlab, data-visualization, scatter-plot

I'm trying to visualize a large amount of data (currently around 1.2 million), distributed among 6 different types, where a type is a different data series.  I'm hoping that visualizing the data will yield some insight into the space that a paticular type occupies.  For example, if I wanted to determine the type of pitch based on the velocity and spin of a baseball, a curveball would be one type, a knuckleball would be another type, etc.

Due to the nature of the data, there are some areas where I have a lot of data, and some areas where I have virtually no data.  The result is that when I plot a specific type, its easy to see the general space that the values should span, but don't because of the missing data points.  In addition, there are areas where there is significant overplotting to the point where it becomes difficult to view individual points.

What I am looking for is a way to populate the areas where I am missing data and a way to reduce the clutter for the areas where I have too much data.  Any ideas?  Thanks so much.

Below is some code so that you can get a better sense of what I'm talking about, ie rotate the image to play around with it.

```
x = [0:.1:.3 .5:.01:.7 1.1:.3:1.7 2:.1:2.3 3:.01:3.3 4:.3:4.5];
y = (0:.1:10) .* randn(1,length(0:.1:10));
[x, y] = meshgrid(x,y);
x = reshape(x,[],1);
y = reshape(y,[],1);
z = (x .^ 2) .* y + randn(length(x),1) .* 5;
plot3(x,y,z,'.');
xlabel('X');
ylabel('Y');
zlabel('Z');
grid on
```

[image: Sample Image of plot of Single Type]

Comment: Do you have the curve fitting toolbox? It includes a function called [`fit`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/curvefit/fit.html) which can be used to fit a surface. From the examples, it says that you can fit a surface like this: `sf = fit( [x, y], z, 'poly23'); plot(sf, [x,y], z)`. I don't have the toolbox so I cannot verify its applicability in this case.

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not have that toolbox, so I won't be able to use that matlab function.  Thanks for the idea though.